Read CSV file with CSV reader and print data
Sample CSV file:

Year,Month
0, 1
5, 3
10,6
15, 4
code:
import csv
with open('Sampledata2Dplot.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
    print(reader)

I am getting the following output:

[['Year', 'Month'], ['0', '1'], ['5', '3'], ['10', '6'], ['15', '4']]

However, I need to read data to list as below

reader = [("Year", "Month"),(0, 1),(5, 3),(10, 6),(15, 4),]

OR

reader = [['Year', 'Month'],[0, 1],[5, 3],[10, 6],[15, 4],]

Finally, my objective is to export this data to excel plotting with openpyxl. How can I do this?

Is your question essentially "How do I get my data as integers rather than strings?"

Dear Jon, Yes, actually I want to read the number (it can be integer, float or a number in exponential format) Further to read data, some times the first column would be a string like NAME and the data in second column would be a number of any type (integer, float or exponential), Thank you

Handle the header and rows separately
import csv

data = []

with open('Sampledata2Dplot.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data.append(next(r))
    for row in r:
        data.append(list(map(int, row)))

print(data)

Result
[['Year', 'Month'], [0, 1], [5, 3], [10, 6], [15, 4]]


If you control the CSV, then a simple solution might be use use the parameter quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC when calling csv.reader(). note that the csv data has been altered with quotes around non-numeric fields here.
import io
import csv

data = """
"Year","Month"
0, 1
5, 3
10,6
15, 4
""".strip()

with io.StringIO(data) as file_in: ## using io.StringIO() to mimic open() for self containment
    reader = csv.reader(file_in, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    print(list(reader))

Should give you:
[['Year', 'Month'], [0.0, 1.0], [5.0, 3.0], [10.0, 6.0], [15.0, 4.0]]

If you don't control the csv at all then @onecricketeer's answer is what I would use or maybe if you have text data blended in then something like:
import io
import csv

def try_parse_numeric(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

data = """
Year,Month
0, 1
5, 3
10,6
15,September
""".strip()

with io.StringIO(data) as file_in:
    result = list(map(
        lambda row: list(map(try_parse_numeric, row)),
        csv.reader(file_in)
    ))
    print(result)

Should result in:
[['Year', 'Month'], [0.0, 1.0], [5.0, 3.0], [10.0, 6.0], [15.0, 'September']]

If you strictly want strings or integers then you can try to return int(value) in that try_parse_numeric(value) method.

Thank you Jon.  I will play with these options. Thank you. By the way, KIndly suggest a good python book for advanced learning and multiprocessing . I notice that there are advanced features which I do not know.

I broke into python from other languages by finding and answering question here on SO. If you find a multi processing question and research the answer you will be helping so.eone else and yourself

Ok fine I will do so. I am working on python with a code development orientation. I am extracting chunks from my C code and testing in Python and then developing python version.
